# How to format numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to change my numbers into thousand format..
For example 100000 into 100K or 190000 to 190K

I thought I could try doing it with Format function but i got no idea on how to do it.
Can anyone help me with query. . . . . .

Comment: formatting data is almost always better performed by the application consuming the data.

Comment: No, you can't do this with the built-in `FORMAT()` function. You could use a `CASE` expression: `CASE WHEN n >= 1000000 THEN ... WHEN n >= 1000 THEN`

Comment: Are you formatting bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, etc.? Could you use the [sys.format_bytes()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-format-bytes.html) function?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope below query idea can help. consider below create table and insert 

create table invoice
(
    id     bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    amount int not null
);

INSERT INTO invoice (id, amount) VALUES (1, 100000);
INSERT INTO invoice (id, amount) VALUES (2, 190000);
INSERT INTO invoice (id, amount) VALUES (3, 192100);

now run below query and observe your expected answer

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (amount / 1000) = ROUND(amount / 1000) THEN CONCAT(FORMAT(amount / 1000, 0), 'K')
        ELSE CONCAT(FORMAT(amount / 1000, 2), 'K')
        END AS formatted_amount
FROM invoice;
```